# How to define separate reactive values from a common user input matrix in R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

In running the reactive code below, the user can input a variable "Y" into the first matrix rendered at the top (generated by function `matInputBase()`) to run a simple scenario where that variable Y appears in only one period in the output, with period set by the slider input for time window "W". The user can optionally input into the following two input matrixes (both generated by function `matInputFlex()`), additional variable Y's into other specified time periods ("X") so long as they fit into overall time window W. Function `matInputFlex()` allows the user to run more detailed scenarios than the basic `matInputBase()`. Note how an input into `matInputBase()` flows directly into the first row and second column of each `matInputFlex()`, as shown in the image below. This part works correctly.

However, if the user has input a scenario into one of the `matInputFlex()` matrixes, and then decides to change any one of the values in `matInputBase()`, then both of the `matInputFlex()` matrixes are reset. I don't want both of the `matInputFlex()` matrixes reset, I would like only the `matInputFlex()` matrix directly affected by the change to the `matInputBase()` matrix to be reset. I would like to preserve the `matInputFlex()` values unaffected by a change to its corresponding parent `matInputBase()` value. So, for if example, if I have built up a `matInputFlex()` scenario for Var_1 and then I change a `matInputBase()` value for Var_2, as shown in the second half of the image below, then only the `matInputFlex()` values for Var_2 should reset and not the `matInputFlex()` values for Var_1. How do I delink these reactive tables, so that Var_1 and Var_2 can process independently?

I have played around with `isolate()` and `observeEvent()` for `input$base_input`, but these changes stopped the flow of inputs from `matInputBase()` to `matInputFlex()`.

Image of how the App works:

[image]

Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)

matInputBase <- function(name) {
  matrixInput(name,
              value = matrix(c(1,2), 2, 1, dimnames = list(c("Var_1", "Var_2"), NULL)),
              rows = list(extend = FALSE, names = TRUE),
              cols = list(extend = FALSE, names = FALSE, editableNames = FALSE),
              class = "numeric"
  )
}

matInputFlex <- function(name, x,y) {
  matrixInput(
    name,
    value = matrix(c(x, y), 1, 2, dimnames = list(NULL, c("X", "Y"))),
    rows = list(extend = TRUE, names = FALSE),
    cols = list(extend = TRUE, delta = 0, names = TRUE, editableNames = FALSE),
    class = "numeric"
  )
}

matStretch <- function(mat, time_window, col_name) {
  mat[, 1] <- pmin(mat[, 1], time_window)
  df <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = time_window, ncol = 1, dimnames = list(NULL, col_name)))
  df[, col_name] <- ifelse(seq_along(df[, 1]) %in% mat[, 1], mat[match(seq_along(df[, 1]), mat[, 1]), 2], 0)
  return(df)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("periods","Time window (W):", min = 1, max = 10, value = 10),
  h5(strong("Var (Y) over time window:")),
  matInputBase("base_input"),
  uiOutput("Vectors"),
  tableOutput("table2")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  base_var_1 <- reactive(input$base_input[1,1])
  base_var_2 <- reactive(input$base_input[2,1])
  
  output$Vectors <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      h5(strong("Adjust Var_1 (Y) at time X:")),
      matInputFlex("var_1_input", input$periods, base_var_1()),
      h5(strong("Adjust Var_2 (Y) at time X:")),
      matInputFlex("var_2_input", input$periods, base_var_2())
      )
    })
  output$table2 <- renderTable(
    cbind(
      matStretch(input$var_1_input, input$periods, "Var_1"),
      matStretch(input$var_2_input, input$periods, "Var_2")
      )
    )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I think this would be most neatly done my using a [module](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html).  The module would take `matInputBase` as a reactive input.  Each *instance* of the module would control a single Y variable and return its adjustments to the main app server function.  The main app server function would `col_bind` the values returned by each module instance into your final data table.  Advantages: (1) It will work (2) it will simplify your main app server code by delegating the separation of effects to the module instances, where the separation will be automatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited `input$periods` event handling from `base_input()` to `isolate(base_input())`.

The code below separates `output$Vectors` into two separate `renderUI` variables in the server, tracks the previous value of `input$base_input` to determine which row has changed (if any), and uses `observeEvent` for more explicit event handling.

It appears to handle `matInputBase` and `matInputFlex` events correctly, and it will reset both `matInputFlex` if `input$periods` changes.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)

matInputBase <- function(name) {
  matrixInput(name,
              value = matrix(c(1,2), 2, 1, dimnames = list(c("Var_1", "Var_2"), NULL)),
              rows = list(extend = FALSE, names = TRUE),
              cols = list(extend = FALSE, names = FALSE, editableNames = FALSE),
              class = "numeric"
  )
}

matInputFlex <- function(name, x,y) {
  matrixInput(
    name,
    value = matrix(c(x, y), 1, 2, dimnames = list(NULL, c("X", "Y"))),
    rows = list(extend = TRUE, names = FALSE),
    cols = list(extend = TRUE, delta = 0, names = TRUE, editableNames = FALSE),
    class = "numeric"
  )
}

matStretch <- function(mat, time_window, col_name) {
  mat[, 1] <- pmin(mat[, 1], time_window)
  df <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = time_window, ncol = 1, dimnames = list(NULL, col_name)))
  df[, col_name] <- ifelse(seq_along(df[, 1]) %in% mat[, 1], mat[match(seq_along(df[, 1]), mat[, 1]), 2], 0)
  return(df)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("periods","Time window (W):", min = 1, max = 10, value = 10),
  h5(strong("Var (Y) over time window:")),
  matInputBase("base_input"),
  # Modified to bring the h5 elements into the UI.
  tagList(
    h5(strong("Adjust Var_1 (Y) at time X:")),
    uiOutput("Vectors1"),
    h5(strong("Adjust Var_2 (Y) at time X:")),
    uiOutput("Vectors2")
  ),
  tableOutput("table2")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # Reactive variable storage
  base_input <- reactive(input$base_input)
  prev <- reactiveValues(
    dat = matrix(c(1,2), 2, 1, dimnames = list(c("Var_1", "Var_2"), NULL))
  )
  
  # Separate out the handling of input$base_input.
  observeEvent(
    input$base_input,
    {
      if (prev$dat[1,1] != base_input()[1,1]){
        output$Vectors1 <- renderUI({
          matInputFlex("var_1_input", input$periods, base_input()[1,1])
        })
      }
      if (prev$dat[2,1] != base_input()[2,1]){
        output$Vectors2 <- renderUI({
          matInputFlex("var_2_input", input$periods, base_input()[2,1])
        })
      }
      # Save the current value for testing the next event.
      prev$dat <- base_input()
    })
  
  # Deal with input$periods events separately.
  observeEvent(
    input$periods,
    {
      output$Vectors1 <- renderUI({
        matInputFlex("var_1_input", input$periods, isolate(base_input())[1,1])
      })
      output$Vectors2 <- renderUI({
        matInputFlex("var_2_input", input$periods, isolate(base_input())[2,1])
      })
      
    })
  
  output$table2 <- renderTable(
    cbind(
      matStretch(input$var_1_input, input$periods, "Var_1"),
      matStretch(input$var_2_input, input$periods, "Var_2")
    )
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: In running this, the same happens as before. If I change or add values to the second input matrix rendered, building a X/Y scenario for Var_1 (generated by `matInputFlex()`), and then go up to the first input matrix (that simpler matrix where you only input Y values, as generated by ´matInputBase()´) and enter a value for Var_2, it also resets the X/Y scenario for Var_1. I am trying to change this where, for example, a change to Y for Var_2 in ´matInputBase()´ only rests the X/Y scenario for Var_2 and not Var_1. And vice versa, a delink. Any change to slider input W should reset all of course.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to isolate the `base_input()` events registered in `input$periods`.

Answer (score 0):

Below is another solution that has withstood many test scenarios. Explanation:

- Key was breaking the reactivity linkage between the 2 rows in the primary input matrix, `base_input[1,1]` and `base_input[2,1]`. For example, when the user inputs into `var_1_input` and then goes up to the second row of the first input matrix and changes a value in `base_input[2,1]`, then the `var_1_input` does not reset; only `var_2_input` resets. Conversely, when user inputs into `var_2_input` and then goes up to the first row of the first input matrix and changes a value in `base_input[1,1]` then the `var_2_input` does not reset; only `var_1_input` resets.
- Reactive value initialization: `prev_base_var_1` and `prev_base_var_2` are initialized without direct reference to `input$base_input`, avoiding immediate reactivity linkage.
- Conditional reactivity: observers for `var_1_input` and `var_2_input` only trigger updates when their respective `base_input` values change, effectively delinking their reactivity.
- Isolated updates: by updating `prev_base_var_1` and `prev_base_var_2` only after confirming a change, the code ensures that unrelated inputs (`var_1_input` or `var_2_input`) do not reset, maintaining their independence.
- This setup allows each variable (`var_1_input` and `var_2_input`) to react only to changes in its corresponding `base_input` element (`base_input[1,1]` and `base_input[2,1]`), achieving the desired delinked reactivity.

Code with comments:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)

matInputBase <- function(name) {
  matrixInput(name,
              value = matrix(c(1,2), 2, 1, dimnames = list(c("Var_1", "Var_2"), NULL)),
              rows = list(extend = FALSE, names = TRUE),
              cols = list(extend = FALSE, names = FALSE, editableNames = FALSE),
              class = "numeric"
  )
}

matInputFlex <- function(name, x,y) {
  matrixInput(
    name,
    value = matrix(c(x, y), 1, 2, dimnames = list(NULL, c("X", "Y"))),
    rows = list(extend = TRUE, names = FALSE),
    cols = list(extend = TRUE, delta = 0, names = TRUE, editableNames = FALSE),
    class = "numeric"
  )
}

matStretch <- function(mat, time_window, col_name) {
  mat[, 1] <- pmin(mat[, 1], time_window)
  df <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = time_window, ncol = 1, dimnames = list(NULL, col_name)))
  df[, col_name] <- ifelse(seq_along(df[, 1]) %in% mat[, 1], mat[match(seq_along(df[, 1]), mat[, 1]), 2], 0)
  return(df)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("periods","Time window (W):", min = 1, max = 10, value = 10),
  h5(strong("Var (Y) over time window:")),
  matInputBase("base_input"),
  uiOutput("Vector"),
  tableOutput("table2")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Initialize previous values for base_input[1,1] and base_input[2,1] as NA
  prev_base_vars <- list(reactiveVal(NA), reactiveVal(NA))
  
  observe({
    # Ensure input$base_input exists and is not NULL
    if (!is.null(input$base_input) && all(!is.na(input$base_input))) {
      
      # Determine the number of rows in base_input
      num_rows <- nrow(input$base_input)
      
      # Loop over each variable
      for (i in 1:num_rows) {
        # Safely access the base_input and previous value
        current_input <- input$base_input[i, 1]
        prev_input <- prev_base_vars[[i]]()
        
        # Check if current_input is different from prev_input and neither is NA
        if (!is.na(current_input) && !is.na(prev_input)) {
          if (current_input != prev_input) {
            matrix_name <- paste0("var_", i, "_input")
            updateMatrixInput(
              session, matrix_name,
              value = matrix(c(input$periods, current_input), 1, 2, dimnames = list(NULL, c("X", "Y")))
            )
            prev_base_vars[[i]](current_input)  # Update the stored previous value
          }
        } else {
          # Initial update if previous value is NA (first run)
          prev_base_vars[[i]](current_input)
        }
      }
    }
  })
  
  output$Vector <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      h5(strong("Adjust Var_1 (Y) at time X:")),
      matInputFlex("var_1_input", input$periods, isolate(input$base_input[1, 1])),
      h5(strong("Adjust Var_2 (Y) at time X:")),
      matInputFlex("var_2_input", input$periods, isolate(input$base_input[2, 1]))
    )
  })
  
  output$table2 <- renderTable(
    cbind(
      matStretch(input$var_1_input, input$periods, "Var_1"),
      matStretch(input$var_2_input, input$periods, "Var_2")
    )
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```